# TFS и автотесты на Java

Tags: java, тестирование, tfs

Добрый день!

Сейчас в компании планируется переход в TFS в связи с чем возникли некоторые вопросы, найти путной информации не получилось поэтому вопрошаю здесь.

Суть в чем сейчас автотесты(написаны на java+selenium), функциональные тесты(jmetter) и нагрузочные тесты(jmetter) запускаются из jenkins. Так вот собственно вопросы:
можно ли это все дело перенести в TFS?
можно ли это все интегрировать с TFS?
Visual Studio Test Professional может ли запускать все эти тесты и выводить результат в виде графиков?
Насколько много крови мы потратим для каждого из сценариев?

Так же если не сложно попросил бы литературы на домашнее чтение по этой теме.

Answer (score 0):

Непонятно с какого репозитория выполняется переход на **TFS**? (Дополните вопрос или напишите в комментариях).
Также непонятно зачем применять технологии Microsoft (имеется вввиду **TFS**), когда есть отлично зарекомендовавшие себя репозитории?
Например **GIT**, **SVN** и т.п.

Но если очень хочется использовать Visual Studio Test Professional, то документация Microsoft сообщает, что есть такая возможность: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/test/continuous-test-java

Comment: У нас сейчас все репозитории в git задачи в jira руководство хочет свести все в одно место